# Populate textbox form access from a query

Tags: ms-access

I want to populate a textbox based on a query which queries another query based on values from a form.

The structure is:

```
form -> query1 -> query2 -> textbox
```

For now I've succeeded to write in vba `me.textbox.requery` but I have 20 textboxes with requery. It takes almost 1 minute to requery the form. I've tried to find something on google but no success. For example something like

```
textbox1.value = queryname.fieldvalue
```

The queries for textboxes have only 1 row because they have sum or count syntax. 
Please help

**EDIT**

1st query is ("preemptiune_zone_query"):

```
SELECT original2.[Numar Tranzactie]
  , original2.[Familie Tranzactie]
  , original2.[NUME 1]
  , original2.zona
  , original2.JUDET
  , original2.[LOCALITATE REALA]
  , IIf([numar_cadastral]<>"" 
    Or [carte_funciara]<>"","Da","Nu") AS Intabulat
  , original2.Numar_Cadastral
  , original2.Carte_Funciara
  , original2.TARLA
  , original2.PARCELA
  , original2.[SUP PARCELA]
  , IIf([sup parcela]>=10000,"Peste 1ha","Sub 1ha") AS [Tip suprafata]
  , original2.[AUTENTIC P]
  , original2.Data_P
  , forma_intelegere.forma_intelegere
  , original2.SOCIETATEA
  , original2.litigiu_status
  , original2.litigiu_probleme
  , maintable_preemptiune.data_contract_arenda_agri
  , IIf(IsNull([data_contract_arenda_agri]),"Nu","Da") AS [Ctr arenda semnat]
  , maintable_preemptiune.nr_inreg_arenda_agri
  , maintable_preemptiune.data_inreg_primarie_arenda_agri
  , IIf(IsNull([data_inreg_primarie_arenda_agri]),"Nu","Da") AS [Ctr arenda inregistrat primarie]
  , maintable_preemptiune.nr_inreg_primarie
  , maintable_preemptiune.data_depunere_oferta_primarie
  , IIf(IsNull([data_depunere_oferta_primarie]),"Nu","Da") AS [Oferta depusa primarie]
  , maintable_preemptiune.termen_ridicare_aviz
  , maintable_preemptiune.aviz_final
  , maintable_preemptiune.nr_aviz
  , maintable_preemptiune.data_aviz
  , maintable_preemptiune.data_expirare_aviz
  , maintable_preemptiune.pvc_reinnoit
FROM forma_intelegere 
INNER JOIN ((original2 
  LEFT JOIN maintable_preemptiune 
  ON original2.[Numar Tranzactie] = maintable_preemptiune.ID_tranzactie) 
 INNER JOIN forma_intelegere_ok 
 ON original2.[Numar Tranzactie] = forma_intelegere_ok.[Numar Tranzactie]) 
ON forma_intelegere.sursa = forma_intelegere_ok.[forma ok]
WHERE (((original2.[Numar Tranzactie]) Like Forms!Preemptiune!id_tranz & "*") 
And ((original2.[Familie Tranzactie]) Like Forms!Preemptiune!familie & "*") 
And ((original2.zona) Like Forms!Preemptiune!zona & "*") 
And ((original2.JUDET) Like Forms!Preemptiune!judet & "*") 
And ((original2.[LOCALITATE REALA]) Like forms!Preemptiune!uat & "*") 
And ((IIf([numar_cadastral]<>"" 
  Or [carte_funciara]<>"","Da","Nu")) Like Forms!Preemptiune!intabulat & "*") 
And ((IIf([sup parcela]>=10000,"Peste 1ha","Sub 1ha")) Like forms!Preemptiune!tip_suprafata & "*") 
And ((forma_intelegere.forma_intelegere) Like forms!Preemptiune!forma_intelegere & "*") 
And ((original2.factor_parcela)=1));
```

This query is updating a subform from a form. In the same form I want to insert textboxes (or labels) which are updated from some queries which query `Query1`.

For example query2:

```
SELECT Sum(preemptiune_zone_query.[SUP PARCELA]) AS Suma_totala
  , Count(preemptiune_zone_query.[SUP PARCELA]) AS nr_parcele_total
FROM preemptiune_zone_query;
```

In the textbox - in Data - Row Source I've inserted the SQL syntax:

```
SELECT Round([Suma_totala]/10000,2) AS Expr1 
FROM sum_suprafata_preemptiune_query;
```

In vba I have:

```
Me.TextBoxName.Requery
```

There are ~20 textboxes, each one queries something.

Comment: Dude, post the queries because that's what is slowing you down. An aggregate query will be relatively slow by nature because you must access all the records and process them. Narrow it down to the queries that are killing you rather than focusing on the form updates.

Comment: I agree with nicomp, I don't think it's your form slowing you down. I don't think a make table query will help either, since the bulk of the processing is executing in Query 1. I'm not great at SQL, but it looks like your WHERE clauses are really filtering your subquery but are called in the aggregate. It might help to move the WHERE clauses to the subquery so that Access isn't pulling more records than it needs.

Comment: I would like in textboxes to be a summary for subform. Let's say the subforms has 100 rows. I want a textbox to show me that I have 100 Rows. I want another textbox to show me The total surface from subform. I want a textbox to show me total surface of some rows filtered by something. So I can't do all this stuff in Query1. I need other queries to query Query1 to get me those values.

Comment: Ah I see, based on the control source, each time you are requerying your text box it has to run query 1 again. Instead, convert query 1 to a make table query and use the resulting table to query for your aggregate measures. That way your text box is looking at the results of query 1 in the table instead of running the whole query again for each text box.

Comment: Good ideea. But I think each requery from each textbox - who have different sql syntax - would still take too long to make. But i will try in vba to run Query 1, run several sql syntax and append result to a table. After that, i will link the textboxes to values from table. I wounder if it will work.

Comment: @Sasu Since your textbox queries return only one row, you could use `DLookup` to set your textbox values. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834404.aspx) If you have a table of the results from Query 1, and write queries to aggregate that data into the values you want to set your text boxes, `DLookup` should get the job done moving the query result to the text box. I think you could put the `DLookups` in your subform requery procedure in VBA.

Comment: I have allready tried with Dlookup but it still takes too long to show results. It takes almost 1 minute to end the procedure. I need something to show result very fast. And very fast doesn't mean 2 seconds, but a resonable time - let's say 10-15 seconds. 1 minute it's too much. My boss doesn't likes wasting time :)